# R data.table calculate function on subset vector for each member of group

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization, subset

I have a data table that is fairly similar to

```
set.seed(1)

dt<-data.table(med=sample(letters,50,T),
    diag=sample(LETTERS[1:7],50,T),
    val=sample(1:100,50,F))
```

I want to calculate the probability of any `val` being greater than `val` for the same `diag`, and assing it to a new column of the table, say `prob` (I'm aware of the fact that the probability not necessarily is normal. I'm OK with that situation).

I can do it with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:50){
    dg<-dt[i,diag]
    vl<-dt[i,val]
    dt$prob[i]<-pnorm(vl,
                      mean(dt[diag==dg,val]),
                      sd(dt[diag==dg,val]),
                      lower.tail = F)
}
```

but my data is fairly big (dt is about 800k rows, with some 2k levels on diag), so I'd like to vectorize instead of looping.

I tried

```
dt[,
   .(lapply(.SD,function(x) 
                pnorm(x[1],
                mean(x),
                sd(x),
                lower.tail = F))),
   by=diag,
   .SDcols="val"]
```

which of course groupss by `diag` yielding only one probability and therefore is of not much use.
I also tried

```
dt[,
   .(lapply(.SD,function(x) 
                pnorm(x[1],
                mean(x),
                sd(x),
                lower.tail = F))),
   by=.EACHI,
   .SDcols="val"]
```

but it produces an error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(lapply(.SD, function(x) pnorm(x[1], mean(x),  : 
  logicial error. i is not data.table, but mult='all' and 'by'=.EACHI
```

What would be the code to produce the desired result with vectorization?

As I'm in the process of getting used to `data.table`s, I'll prefer a solution that uses that package, however I'm absolutely open to any other solution sources (plyr, dplyr, etc).

Thanks,

Comment: `dt[,prob2:= 1 - pnorm(val,mean(val),sd(val),lower.tail=FALSE),by=diag]` or something similar seems to match your result. Not sure why I need to do `1 - pnorm` though.

Comment: Wouldn't result be of length 7? I want a result of length 50, with `prob` calculated *for each* row, it's just that it's calculated by taking into account the distribution of all values that *share* the same `diag`

Comment: nope, `by=` does the calculations for each row in each group by default. That's the whole point.

Comment: I have a couple problems with your example. 50 is more than you need and takes up a lot of space if displayed in an answer to demonstrate a result. And your example is randomly generated but you have not set a seed, so it is not reproducible.

Comment: `dt[,prob2:= pnorm(val,mean(val),sd(val),lower.tail=FALSE),by=diag]` gives the same result now - the `1 -` was only needed because you used `lower.tail=F` not `lower.tail=FALSE` and I had a variable called `F` floating about. A good reason to type `FALSE` and `TRUE` out in full.

Comment: For what it's worth using an apply function isn't better for performance than a for loop.  If you look at the code behind apply you'll see it is nothing but a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `data.table`:

```
dt[, prob2 := pnorm(val, mean(val), sd(val), lower.tail=FALSE), by=diag]
```

Seems to match what you want:

```
head(dt)
#   med diag val       prob      prob2
#1:   p    E  91 0.04713131 0.04713131
#2:   f    E   3 0.92991675 0.92991675
#3:   o    B  26 0.83792988 0.83792988
#4:   t    C  38 0.70877125 0.70877125
#5:   g    E  71 0.16909178 0.16909178
#6:   i    E  25 0.75428819 0.75428819
```

Comment: I didn't even consider trying this, and that's why I went with `.SD`. I don't fully understand how, in the call to `pnorm` it makes the difference between the first `val`  being a value and the second and third being vectors. I thought that if I called `pnorm` on `val`, then I would get a vector as a result. I appreciate if you help me understanding why it's not so. Thanks

Comment: @PavoDive - `pnorm` is vectorized. Given `pnorm(1:3,mean=mean(1:10),sd=sd(1:10))` it will loop over `1:3`, 'recycling' the single values for the mean (`5.5`)  and sd (`3.02`) for each calculation. It is essentially the same as `pnorm(1,mean(1:10),sd(1:10)); pnorm(2,mean(1:10),sd(1:10)); pnorm(3,mean(1:10),sd(1:10))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
dt %>% group_by(diag) %>% 
       mutate(prob = pnorm(val, mean(val), sd(val), lower.tail = FALSE))
```